# Forward Avahi mDNS packets from one network to another

Tags: routing, multicast, linux

I have a Linux device connected to two different networks. `eth0` is connected to `198.18.248.x` and `wlan0` is connected to `198.19.255.x`. Another device connected to the `198.18.248.x` network and it's broadcasting Avahi mDNS services. How can I forward the mDNS packets from the `198.18.248.x` network to `198.19.255.x` (from eth0 to wlan0) so that anyone connected on `198.19.255.x` would see the avahi services from `198.18.248.x`? Is it even possible?

Thanks

Comment: You should consider a proper network setup using regular DNS.

Comment: Unfortunately, questions about hosts/servers and protocols above OSI layer-4 are off-topic here. You could try to ask this question on [sf] for a business network.

Comment: The solution is probably having an avahi reflector ( https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man5/avahi-daemon.conf.5.html#section%20[reflector] )

Answer (score 5):

Zeroconf Networking [RFC 6272](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6762), [RFC 6273](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6763) has the fundamental design constraint of being "local subnet only".

Zeroconf's multicast packets have a TTL of 255, and if you try *forward* these through a router, TTL is decremented by 1 (that's what routers do...). Zeroconf implementations I have come across drop the packets they receive if the packet's TTL is <255. There's a reference to that in RFC 6272, p.37:

> All Multicast DNS responses (including responses sent via unicast)
> SHOULD be sent with IP TTL set to 255.  This is recommended to
> provide backwards-compatibility with older Multicast DNS queriers
> (implementing a draft version of this document, posted in February
> 2004) that check the IP TTL on reception to determine whether the
> packet originated on the local link.  These older queriers discard
> all packets with TTLs other than 255.

Even using a "multicast helper" will not help here; while it can convert multicast packets from one subnet to unicast packets in the other, TTL will still be decremented.

To make it work, you'll need software on a dual homed system/host acting as gateway, "recaster" or proxy server.

Some network vendors have a "service discovery gateway" feature. I do know that Cisco IOS and IOS XE based routers have it.  It is described here: https://www.cisco.com/en/US/docs/ios-xml/ios/ipaddr_dns/configuration/15-e/dns-serv-disc-gtw.html

> Service Discovery Gateway
>
> The Service Discovery Gateway feature enables multicast Domain Name
> System (mDNS) to operate across Layer 3 (L3) boundaries (different
> subnets). An mDNS gateway will be able to provide transport for
> service discovery across Layer 3 boundaries by filtering, caching and
> extending services from one L3 domain (subnet) to another. Prior to
> implementation of this feature, mDNS was limited in scope to within a
> subnet due to the use of link-local scoped multicast addresses. This
> feature enhances Bring Your Own Device (BYOD).

Comment: Thanks, I'm not using any router from any big vendor, I'm trying to do this on a custom linux device running openwrt.